# My android app can not obtain new data from mysql through PHP

Tags: android, caching

I have an android app code that reads data from mySQL database using php scripts. it reads the data correctly the first time. However, if i update the data in the database manually from the database,the app will show the data which was read the very first time the code was run. if i change the url of the php scripts, then the android app code will be able to read the updated data. below is my android code which read data from php.

the value in `Log.d("parserclass here", json);` will always show the data that was first read when the php script is uploaded. i have verified that the php script is correct by using internet explorer or other web browser to attempt read the data from mySQL.

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public void shutdown(){
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();


            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("parserclass here", json);
            reader.reset();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626123/httpclient-response-not-get-refresh

Comment: use a timestamp {read how to generate one based on actual datetime} as parameter added to your params. This way every time the url will be seen as "new" and will  got new data (on GET) example myurl = www... ?params&timestamp=3178739817313

Comment: Hello, i added timestamp using the following.
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String currentTime_string = df.format(currentTime);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", currentTime_string));

it still doesnt work